# window.open() is not always displaying the expected url

Tags: javascript, window.open

I'm trying to figure out the behavior of `window.open()`. I have the following function that is run when a user clicks on a button:

```
urls = // an array of urls
function gotoactivity(idnum) {
    $('#' + idnum).text('completed!').removeClass('active').addClass('disabled');
    var instructions = window.open('', 'instructions', 'left=20,top=20,width=160,height=300,menubar=no,titlebar=no');
    console.log(urls[idnum]);
    var workspace = window.open(urls[idnum], 'workspace', 'left=200,top=20,width=1195,height=750,menubar=no,titlebar=no,scrollbars=yes');
    instructions.document.body.innerHTML = instructionsHTML;
};
```

What is puzzling me is that the url that is displayed by `console.log()` is not always the same one that appears in the url bar when `window.open()` opens the `workspace` window on the very next line! Instead, `window.open()` sometimes opens a page with the query string missing from the url.

I recognize that my bug is probably elsewhere in my code, but I'm baffled at how `window.open` is displaying something that is different than what is console logged on the immediately previous line. Any thoughts on why this might happen are most welcome. I don't write JavaScript very often so I appreciate your patience!

Thank you!

Comment: Does it open the popup with the wrong URL already - or is there maybe some server-side redirect involved (so that what you see in the address bar is not what was originally opened any more) ...? Use dev tools/network panel to check.

Comment: I don't see a redirect, but maybe I'm missing something. The network panel just shows jquery and bootstrap loading. I'm running this on localhost, which hopefully simplifies things. I'm also curious as to why it might only redirect every once in a while, not every time. Happens with different urls, too.